# Typescript: how do I refer to DOM definitions in .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript

I have an app that compiles Javascript both for the browser and for webworkers. If I refer to Typescript's DOM definition for `HTMLButtonElement` in a `.d.ts` file, the compilation says `Cannot find name 'HTMLButtonElement'`.

For example, `foo.d.ts`:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  getButtonInfo: (element: HTMLButtonElement) => Info;
}
```

I have `tsconfig`'s `lib` option using `dom`, so things like `HTMLButtonElement` are accepted as ambient in other parts of the application. How do I refer to `HTMLButtonElement` in a `.d.ts` file?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.worker.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/worker",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you can add `/// <reference lib="dom" />` to the top to import the DOM definitions - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-lib-

Comment: @​Joseph - This Just Works™ in the normal case, so it's something about your nesting structure. Please update the question with a MCVE with the paths of each file, a sample `.ts` file using `SomeInterface`, etc., so we can copy and paste those exactly into the same structure that you have.

Comment: @romellem - But they shouldn't have to, it should get picked up from the `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: After experimenting a bit with `/// <reference lib="dom" />`, I noticed lots of unexpected typing conflicts. The project has webworkers that are configured separately: the error was apparently coming from the webworker compilation. (Which is good: webworkers have no access to the DOM.) Issue was resolved by using tsconfig's 'exclude' property in (the previously unmentioned) `tsconfig.worker.json` to exclude the relevant `.d.ts` file. I'll update the question to describe the full use case, and document my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a bit, it turned out that the error was being thrown when Typescript was trying to compile the webworkers. As can be seen in `tsconfig.worker.json`, it has its own `lib` definition, which validly did not include `"dom"`, since webworkers have no access to the DOM. I needed to `exclude` the `.d.ts` file that included references to the DOM, like so:

tsconfig.worker.json:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.worker.ts"
  ],
"exclude": [
    "src/**/[offending file].d.ts"
  ]
```